# How can i get my chartjs to show up graphically?

Tags: chart.js

for example, when i load the page, i would like to visually appear slowly, instead of just popups already loaded

For example, when i load this bar graph, everything appears slowly with the nice visualization onto the screen, i think it adds a nice affect

this is my script

```
    <script>
            var department = {{department|safe}};
            var incomplete = {{incomplete|safe}};
            var complete = {{complete|safe}};

            // Return with commas in between
            var numberWithCommas = function (x) {
                return x.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
            };

            // Chart.defaults.global.elements.rectangle.backgroundColor = '#FF0000';

            var bar_ctx = document.getElementById('bar-chart');
            var bar_chart = new Chart(bar_ctx, {
                type: 'bar',
                data: {
                    labels: department,
                    datasets: [
                    {
                        label: 'incomplete',
                        data: incomplete,
                        backgroundColor: "rgba(55, 160, 225, 0.7)",
                        hoverBackgroundColor: "rgba(55, 160, 225, 0.7)",
                        hoverBorderWidth: 2,
                        hoverBorderColor: 'lightgrey'
                    },
                    {
                        label: 'complete',
                        data: complete,
                        backgroundColor: "rgba(225, 58, 55, 0.7)",
                        hoverBackgroundColor: "rgba(225, 58, 55, 0.7)",
                        hoverBorderWidth: 2,
                        hoverBorderColor: 'lightgrey'
                    },
                    ]
                },
                options: {
                    animation: {
                        duration: 10,
                    },
                    tooltips: {
                        mode: 'label',
                        callbacks: {
                            label: function (tooltipItem, data) {
                                return data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex].label + ": " + numberWithCommas(tooltipItem.yLabel);
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    scales: {
                        xAxes: [{
                            stacked: true,
                            gridLines: { display: false },
                        }],
                        yAxes: [{
                            stacked: true,
                            ticks: {
                                callback: function (value) { return numberWithCommas(value); },
                            },
                        }],
                    }, // scales
                    legend: { display: true }
                } // options
            }
            );

    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the `options` object, there is an `animation` parameter:

`animation: {
    duration: 10,
},`

I believe this is what you want.

Comment: hmm, i have that, but it doesn't load the graph slowly, it just pops up with everything